# jquery highlight row with a twist

Tags: jquery

I'm not very good a jQuery, but i'm trying to figure out a way to highlight the row in a table that my mouse is over (say green).  There is only one table on the page.  I found jQuery that will make this happen

```
$("tr").filter(function () {
    return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
}).css({
    background: "ffffff"
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        background: "#C1DAD7"
    });},function () {
    $(this).css({
        background: "#ffffff"
    });
});
```

but I need to go a step further.  if I click on a row, I want that row to be highlighted a different color (red) then the hover and also stay highlighted red unless another row is clicked on.  So the hover highlights the row unless it's been clicked on.  After a row has been clicked on, the hover still works, just not on the clicked row and the clicked row stays red unless another row is clicked.  Is there a way to do this.

I know the color above don't match red or green

Comment: Sounds like you should use much more CSS for that, and use JS only to toggle the clicked state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were you, i would use classes instead of direct styling :

**JS**

```
$("tr").filter(function () {
    return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
}).hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
}).click(function(){
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

**CSS**

```
.hover{
    background : #C1DAD7;
}

.clicked{
    background : #f00;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9wgGQ/

Comment: thanks.. question.. in your fiddle example, the click event, its attached to hover or the div..  just trying to figure the order it uses to learn more.  Also, if you willing, if I need to set one of the rows on page load to use or be set to the "clicked" class, what is a good way to go about that.  Do I need to name the div's and do it that way.. curious what a good approach would be. Thanks

Comment: For your first question, the event is binded to the div (or tr in your case). Jquery allow you to chain method with 1 stack : `$(selector).method1().method2()...`. For your second question, you can select the first tr of the stack and simulate a click with `.trigger` : `.click(code already here).first().trigger('click')`

Comment: I understand better what you are saying... the first().trigger('click') I also understand.  I've been trying to work this out myself but it's getting pretty ugly and there has to be a better way then what i'm doing.  What my end goal is, I have a table with 4 rows.  when someone clicks on a row, I need to also update a hidden input with the value of a hidden input in that row so I can store what value was selected.  By the same measure, on page load, I need may need to highlight a row other than then first row where I pickup on a hidden value. hope your still willing to help share.  Thanks

Comment: @jvcoach23 Take a look at this code : http://jsfiddle.net/9wgGQ/1/. If you search every function on the jQuery API, you'll be able to understand!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('tr').css({background:'none'});
  $(this).css({ background: '#FF0000'});
});
```

Use this for the background [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F5acQ/)

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/88r7p/

```
$("table tr").hover(
        function () { $(this).css({ background: "#C1DAD7" }); },
        function () { $(this).css({ background: "whitesmoke" }); }
).click(function() {
 $('table tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```